# Did a successful Core Data migration but the existing store was deleted

Tags: core-data, magicalrecord

I have a CoreData store managed with MagicalRecord.  I did a successful migratiion, but lost the data in the newly created store.  This is what I have:

[image]

salonbookV1.0 is the original xcdatamodel for the initial store.  I added only new attributes to an existing entity, and the mappingmodel looks like this: (a partial image).

[image]

Let me elaborate on what I did...

- created the xcdatamodeld folder with both xcdatamodel's in it
- marked the salonbookV1.0 as the current version and ran the app creating some entries
- stopped the app, and marked salonbookV1.5 as the current version and ran the app
- data which was entered previously was gone!  (apparently the migration did not occur)?

The migration was accomplished; I know that because I can use the new attributes.  However, the existing CD store was deleted.  I have read all I can on MR, and there is only one method that deals with migration; MR does the rest without any coding from me.

So the question remains: why is the existing store being deleted?

Comment: What changes to the code are you doing? Migrations won't happen unless you tell core data to do one.

Comment: It was my understanding that MagicalRecord *would do everything* for me automatically... not true?

Comment: At some point, you're going to have to write some code. Take a look at the magicalrecord class headers to see what options you have to help you with migrations

Comment: @casademora: Have you ever done a migration using MagicalRecord?

Comment: OK... so where is the doc that shows the code that I need to add?  I have spent two days working on this, getting nowhere!  I would really appreciate your help in pointing me to a doc that would help me.

Comment: It almost sounds like you just didn't save changes after creating the v1.0 data, so there was nothing to migrate. Did you verify that the data was saved before attempting the migration?

Comment: Oh, yes... this was data that had been there for quite a few runs...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about MR but in "normal" Core Data you have to set the `NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption` to the persistent store, otherwise it will not migrate your existing data to the new store version.

Comment: I did read your question. There is a distinction between migrating the new model and migrating the data. I thought option mentioned by me refers to the data, not the model, which upon further reasearch does not seem to be the case. -- BTW, you will not get any useful answers as a trigger-happy down-voter.

Comment: Your comment didn't make much sense to me since I'm using MR and it's all about the data; I apologize for the down-vote.  I'm just very frustrated with this! :-{